# how to restore the calendar view created by the calendar module?

Tags: views, datetime

When you install the calendar module a calendar view is automatically created. For some reason it seems that I deleted this view. Now I need to use the calendar module and I need this view.

The version of the module is: **7.x-3.4**

I can't find a way to make that the calendar module recreate that view. This is what I did:

1) I disabled the calendar module

2) I uninstall the calendar module

3) I enabled the calendar module again

But the view is not created at all.

How can I have this view restored.

Comment: Clear cache and check the views listing page ?

Comment: Drupal 7.15 and Calendar 7.x-3.4

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: http://vimeo.com/26853285 **Is it outdated?**

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple.
Go to Home » Administration » Structure » Views and add new view from template.
Yo could see in this section different calendar views. 
Regards